# Configurar boostrap-tables en proyecto laravel mediante webpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, bootstrap

tengo instalado y funcionando boostrap-tables en un proyecto de laravel 6, las tablas me estan funcionando , no consigo que me muestre el idioma en es_ES y por defecto me sale en inglés.

La configuración que tengo es la siguiente

**Webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');



mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js'
], 'public/js/app.js').extract([
    // './resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js',
    // 'bootstrap',
], 'public/js/vendors.js').version();


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Luego ejecuto el comando "npm run watch" y veo que me genera el fichero /resources/js/app.js donde veo un buen trozo de código de bootstrap-tables

Luego tengo el fichero del HEAD del laoyout donde cargo todas las librerias, con el siguiente contenido

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Scotch">

<title>COCHES</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Y para terminar, el código html donde muestro el bootstrap-table, como comento funciona a la perfección pero no me muestra las traducciones en español.

```
        <table
        id="table-cars-list"
        data-locale="es-ES"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-pagination="true"
        data-search="false"
        data-url = {{ route('api.cars.list', ['user_id' =>   Session::get('user_id') ]) }}>

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Nombre</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Te fijaste en el app.js si efectivamente están los datos del locale de bootstrap-table?

Otra cosa que yo haría es no mezclarlo todo en el app.js, simplemente lo importas así como está;

```
mix.js('resources/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js', 'public/js');
```

Y en tu aplicación lo invocas aparte;

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js') }}"></script>
```

En teoría con esto no sería necesario inicializar nada más, porque el .js ya tiene un inicializador según se ve en [la documentación](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/localizations/) y en el [contenido del archivo](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/locale/bootstrap-table-es-ES.js)

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier, me ha funcionado tal cual. Muchas gracias por todo.